# add child entity to an exsisting parent hibernate onetomany

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am new to hibernate
i want to add child to an exsisting parent entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="kanban_col")
public class kanban_columns {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    private String id;

    @Column(name="col_name")
    private String colName;

    @Column(name="kbid")
    private String boardId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "kanban_col_id",cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST,orphanRemoval = true,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Tasks> tasks;

    Getter and setters....
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="kanban_tasks")
public class Tasks {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    private String id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonBackReference
    @JoinColumn(name = "cid", updatable = true, insertable = true,referencedColumnName = "id")
    private kanban_columns kanban_col_id;

    @Column(name="work_id")
    private String workId;

Getter and setters....
}
```

service

```
    @Transactional
    public kanban_columns createTask(final kanban_columns source) {
        final kanban_columns destination = new kanban_columns();

        copyTask(source, destination);

        repository.save(destination);

        return destination;
    }

    @Transactional
    public void save(final kanban_columns attachment)
    {
        repository.save(attachment);
    }
 public void copyTask(final kanban_columns source, final kanban_columns destination){
        destination.setTasks(source.getTasks());
    }
```

```
{
    "kanban_col_id":"ff80808174f95b8c0174f95ba1e30000",
        "tasks":[{
        "workId":"4028ab37735ae04e01735b4833ba0000"
    },
{
        "workId":"4028ab37735ae04e01735b4833ba0001"
    },
]
    
}
```

I am trying to do but a new row in `kanban_col` is created but i need to insert into existing one
please tell me how to add new row in child entity for existing parent in @onetomany and  also how to update,delete child row for existing  parent
thank you..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create the new instance of `kanban_columns` in the `createTask` method, so the new row is added in the database. You should find the existing `kanban_columns` with the associated tasks and then add a new task to list.

You need a new method in the repository, that loads and returns the kanban_columns instance with the already associated tasks:

```
@Query("select kc from kanban_columns kc left join fetch kc.tasks where kc.id = :id")
kanban_columns findByIdWithTasks(@Param("id") String id);
```

Define in the `kanban_columns` a helper method:

```
public void addTasks(Collection<Task> tasks) {
    tasks.forEach(t -> t.setKanban_column_id(this));
    this.tasks.addAll(tasks);
}
```

And your `createTask` and `copyTask` methods should be changed to:

```
@Transactional
public kanban_columns createTask(final kanban_columns source) {
    final kanban_columns destination = repository.findByIdWithTasks(souce.getId());

    copyTask(source, destination);

    repository.save(destination);

    return destination;
}

public void copyTask(final kanban_columns source, final kanban_columns destination) {
    destination.addTasks(source.getTasks());
}
```

To delete a task you will need to change cascade from `PERSIST` to `ALL` and define a similar method in the kanban_columns:

```
public void deleteTask(Task task) {
    this.tasks.remove(task);
}
```

Comment: null value is getting set at column cid and work_id in task table

Comment: Did you define `addTasks` method in the kanban_columns class and did you use it to add the tasks?

Comment: yes i have define addTasks method at kanban_columns  class

Comment: I need to see your current code to be able to help.

Comment: I heaved fixed the issue  thank you so much for your help .can you give some hint to implement for update task

Comment: Give me please more info how do you want to update a task?

Comment: I want to update "cid" in "kanban_task" table for a particular task

Comment: want to update "kanban_col_id" to the other ids of my "kanban_col" table have

Comment: The simplest way is just to set a new `kanban_columns` value to the `kanban_col_id` field of the task and then call `repository.save(task)`. Note that repository should be JpaRepository<Tasks, String> instance, or CrudRepository<Tasks, String>.

Comment: I have tried but it not working             https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64237464/update-joinned-table-id-in-hibernate-onetomany-not-working

Comment: What exception?

Comment: Or just the update does not saved in DB without any exception? In this case make sure your service method is transactional and not read only.